# recaptcha_tags rendering escaped HTML in erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, recaptcha

I'm migrating my app to Rails 3.2.8 from 2.3.5. One form uses reCAPTCHA (in an erb file). Right now, all the HTML tags that the recaptcha_tags puts out are in escaped HTML. (i.e. &lt;...&gt; instead of <...>). So I see the tags themselves in the HTML page, instead of the reCAPTCHA box.

Here's what my erb looks like. I've verified that it doesn't matter where in the erb I put the recaptcha tags (inside the form_for or outside):

register.html.erb

```
...
<%= recaptcha_tags :public_key => RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY %>
...
```

Other things, like form_for don't have this problem. They output straight HTML.

Gemfile

```
gem "recaptcha", :require => 'recaptcha/rails'
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I needed to prefix the recaptcha_tags call with "raw":

register.html.erb

```
...
<%= raw recaptcha_tags :public_key => RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY %>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the major changes between Rails 2.3.5 and 3.X was some changes having to do with cross site scripting.  You may want to start your upgrade by upgrading to 2.3.14 and adding the rails_xss gem.  The rails_xss gem (https://github.com/rails/rails_xss) will switch the HTML safety default to escape, so it will cause the issue you're seeing with recaptcha_tags.  This will allow you to see what strings in your app need to be marked as html_safe.

Or, if recaptcha_tags is the only issue, you may be able to fix it by telling rails not to escape the recaptcha_tags.

Something like:

```
<%= raw recaptcha_tags :public_key => "_________" %>
```

- Thanks for doing the research. :)

Comment: Thanks. The .html_safe method didn't work for me. However, I did some further searching based on your comment, and found that prefixing the recaptcha_tags call with "raw" solves the problem. (I'll post that as the answer shortly).